# I keep getting an error saying "Could not find or load main class gradebooktest.GradeBookTest" I am not sure why

Tags: java

I am using netbeans and my code is as follows

```
public class GradeBook
{
    private String courseName; // course name for this GradeBook
    private String courseInstructor; // instructor name for this GradeBook 

// constructor initializes courseName and courseInstructor with String Argument
    public GradeBook( String name, String insname ) // constructor name is class name
    {
        courseName = name; // initializes courseName
        courseInstructor = insname; // initializes courseInstructor 
    } // end constructor

    // method to set the course name
    public void setCourseName( String name )
    {
        courseName = name; // store the course name
    } // end method setCourse

    // method to retrieve the course name
    public String getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName;
    } // end method getCourseName

    // method to set the Instructor name 
    public void setInstructorName( String insname)
    { 
        courseInstructor = insname; // store the Instructor name 
    } // end method setInstructorName 

    // method to retrieve the Instructor name 
    public String getInstructorName()
    { 
        return courseInstructor; 
    } // end method getInstructorName 

    // display a welcome message to the GradeBook user
    public void displayMessage()
    {
        // this statement calls getCourseName to get the 
        // name of the course this GradeBook represents
        System.out.println( "\nWelcome to the grade book for: \n"+
        getCourseName()+"\nThis course is presented by: "+getInstructorName()); 
        System.out.println( "\nProgrammed by Jack Friedman");

    } // end method displayMessage
} // end
```

Comment: You are trying to launch an application without main class? Sounds weird..

Answer (score 1):

You should call the constructor of this class in your main method.

Make a new class GradeBookTest as follows:

```
public class GradeBookTest {

  public static void main (String args[]) {
     GradeBook book = new GradeBook("Math", "T.I.");
    book.displayMessage(); //To see your results
   }

}
```

Now you can launch this class to view your results.

Comment: Where would I put this? In another file or somewhere in this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should create another class GradeBookTest(as in my example) in same package as your model, or if you want, you can create it in another package and import  this POJO (your BookGrade) class.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a static main method to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the main method? Include below code to run your program-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      GradeBook book = new GradeBook("subj1", "instruc1");
      book.displayMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method whose signature is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

`main` method is the entry point for a java program, it has to be declared as `public` so that it can be accessed from outside the class and `static` so that it can be accessed even without creating an instance or object of the class.

For better understanding please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/)